# New Data Added to DataTable is not being Deleted

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using the following JQuery code to add the data to dataTable:

```
$('#orderList').DataTable().row.add([
        resp.counter,
        resp.quantity,
        resp.width,
        resp.height,
        resp.cost,
        resp.action
    ]).draw(false);
```

This is the code I am responding from the server via ajax:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => 'success',
    "amount" => $amounts->fetch_object()->amount,
    "counter" => "#1",
    "quantity" => "<input type='number' value='".$quantity."' class='form-control orderListAlterQuantity' placeholder='Qty'>",
    "width" => $_POST['formDat'][0]['width']." CM",
    "height" => $_POST['formDat'][0]['width']." CM",
    "cost" => "Rs. ".$cost."/-",
    "action" => "<button data-orderid='".$orderID."' class='orderListDeleteEntry btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger waves-effect waves-light m-r-10'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></button>"
));
```

The above code works as follows:

When I add data from a form, it is sent to the server. When the server processes it after adding in the database I am responding it via `json_encode` so that I can process in success function of ajax to add to the `DataTable`. The data is added to the table. Problem is that after I click the delete button it doesn't delete the data from the DataTable but it is deleted from the server.

This is the code that i am using to process whenever the delete button is clicked:

```
    $("body").on('click', 'button.orderListDeleteEntry', function(event)    
    {
        var id = $(this).data("orderid");
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).html("Deleting..");
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'true');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/alter',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {type: "delete", orderid: id},
        })
        .done(function(resp)
            {
                if(resp.status == "success")
                    {
                        $('table#orderList tbody tr#'+id).fadeOut("slow");
                        // $('#orderList').DataTable().row("#"+id).slideUp("slow");
                        // $('table#orderList tbody tr#'+id).remove();
                        // $this.parents('tr').remove().draw();
                        $('#orderList').DataTable().row("#"+id).remove().draw(false);
                        $('#orderList').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(false);
                        $("span#orderTotalAmt").html(resp.amount);
                        // alert("Order Deleted");
                    }

                else if(resp.status == "failed")
                    {
                        $this.html("<i class='fa fa-close'></i>");
                        $this.removeAttr('disabled');
                        // alert("Problem Deleting Order! Please Try Again after Sometime.");
                    }

                else
                    {
                        $this.html("<i class='fa fa-close'></i>");
                        $this.removeAttr('disabled');
                    }
            })
        .fail(function(resp)
            {
                console.log(resp);
            });
    });
```

Why is it happening so?

This is the Button location:

It's Like this:

```
`<tr id="180" role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">#1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control orderListAlterQuantity" placeholder="Qty">
    </td>
    <td>20 CM</td>
    <td>20 CM</td>
    <td class="updatedAmount">Rs. <span class="totalPriceForThisItem">3200</span>/-</td>
    <td>
        <button data-orderid="180" class="orderListDeleteEntry btn btn-rounded btn-outline-danger waves-effect waves-light m-r-10"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>`
```

Comment: Are you seeing any exception in your browser console?

Comment: Nopes there is no error, warning, an exception in the console.

Comment: Did you check by adding a console log in your button click? Is that getting invoked first of all

Comment: means how i didn't get it?

Comment: once add console.log() in your done callback and let me know if its displayed in console

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> ```
> $('#orderList').DataTable().row("#"+id).remove().draw(false);
> ```

And use

> $this.parent().parent().remove()

as $this is referencing the button then .parent().parent() will refer the row and .remove() delete it.

Comment: Nopes that didn't work if I increase one more `.parent` then the whole tr from the row is deleted

Comment: then there must be one more HTML tag in <tr> tag.  I added it as suppose <tr> <td><button /></td></tr> so according to me <tr> is the second parent

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: i ve updated the question please see the desired format